# Examples of HTML Table usage

Tags: html, html-table

I'm relatively new with HTML and am creating a website that plans to use a list comparable to the Windows Explorer 'Show as Details' option.

I'm sure tables have this ability and are even made to implement exactly that however playing around with them I can't seem to get them to work as I'd expect. Google then fails to give me any good resources.

You know any?

Comment: Describe the problem you are having, with more detail please.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: I'm looking for tutorials or examples on how to use Tables in HTML.

Comment: You say you've been trying but it's not working the way you want.  Why not post your attempt so we can tell you what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

A table in HTML can be quite simple with only a few tags or more complicated. A simple table could have just the opening and closing table tags and then inside a set of table row tags (tr) and another of table data tags (td). But if you've been experimenting with them a bit you probably want more advanced tables. Since I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for try the W3C Schools site like Brabster said: (http://www.w3schools.com/). Go to the HTML section and look at the tables category. Sorry I can't be more helpful, could you please be a little more specific with the problem you're having?